# NSArray Loop to grab Objects

Tags: objective-c, ipad, object, for-loop, nsarray

I'm currently in the development process of an application which needs to be able to grab two objects from an NSArray and then store it in another object.

I've currently got this fast enumeration loop going on,

```
NSUInteger count = 0;
NSUInteger i = count + 1;
for (id item in [section items]) {


    item1 = [section.items objectAtIndex:count];
    item2 = [section.items objectAtIndex:i];

    count++;

}
```

Now, what I want to do is grab the object in the first position and store in item1, and then the second position will be stored in item2. The next time it goes through the loop, I want it to store the object in the third position in item1, and then the fourth position in item2 and so forth.

Has anyone ever tried to and achieved this?

**EDIT**

This is what I currently have, I thought it best that I explain what I'm doing a little deeper so here goes. Here's the code that I have first, and I'll explain afterwards.

```
MPSection *section = [self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSArray *itemArray = [section items];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; (i + 1) < [section.items count]; i += 2) {
    item1 = [itemArray objectAtIndex:i];
    item2 = [itemArray objectAtIndex:i+1];
}
```

As you can see, this is running within `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` as I want to grab what would normally be displayed in the first and second row of a UITableView and put it into one cell which is divided into two subviews.

What I'm finding is, by using the above code, it definitely isn't doing that. Is there a simpler way that I can do this and if so, can someone please inform me about this. I really need to approach this with memory preservation and time consumption kept to a minimal as well.

Comment: Is `MPSection *section = [self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` correct? or did you mean `MPSection *section = [self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]`;?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be good if you can preprocess this but if you can't do that for some reason then this is what you should do,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    MPSection * section = [self.sections objectAtIndex:section];
    NSInteger   count   = [section.items count];

    return ((count % 2 == 0)? count / 2 : (count / 2 + 1) );
}
```

And in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method,

```
/* */

MPSection *section = [self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

id item1 = [section.items objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2)];
id item2 = ((indexPath.row * 2 + 1) < [section.items count])? [section.items objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2 + 1)] : nil;

/* Use item1 & item2 to fill both the subviews */
```

#### Original Answer

Use the `NSEnumerator` instance for this purpose

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [section.items objectEnumerator];
id item1, item2;
while ( (item1 = [enumerator nextObject]) && (item2 = [enumerator nextObject]) ) {
    // Use item1 & item2
}
```

As such I think you must be getting index out of bounds error for the snippet you mentioned.

**Overkill**

There seems to be some question about performance so I tested the three suggested methods and timed them in a loop where I log them.

```
Enumerator, Fast Enumeration with Object Search, For Loop (50000 elements): 19.253626, 88.269961, 18.767572
Enumerator, Fast Enumeration with Object Search, For Loop (25000 elements): 9.164311, 25.105664, 8.777443
Enumerator, Fast Enumeration with Object Search, For Loop (10000 elements): 3.428265, 6.035876, 3.144609
Enumerator, Fast Enumeration with Object Search, For Loop (5000 elements): 2.010748, 2.548562, 1.980477
Enumerator, Fast Enumeration with Object Search, For Loop (1000 elements): 0.508310, 0.389402, 0.338096
Enumerator, Fast Enumeration with Object Search, For Loop (500 elements): 0.156880, 0.163541, 0.150585
Enumerator, Fast Enumeration with Object Search, For Loop (100 elements): 0.076625, 0.034531, 0.036576
Enumerator, Fast Enumeration with Object Search, For Loop (50 elements): 0.026115, 0.022686, 0.041745
```

From the looks of it, @Caleb's `for` loop approach might be the best approach to take.

Comment: He's clearly using NSFastEnumeration though, which handles the enumeration automatically. I feel like this is overkill.

Comment: Why overkill? It's a much better solution than fast enumeration, which forces you to take the objects one at a time. This solution takes the objects in pairs, which is exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Great -- thanks for taking the time to test! It might be interesting to test cases with 200,000, 300,000, and 400,000 objects -- apparently [300,000 is where NSArray will surprise you](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/).

Comment: BTW, I like your solution the best. It may be slightly slower than my traditional for loop and functionally equivalent to my enumerator solution, but putting both assignments in the condition is clean and directly expresses the intent that the OP expressed.

Comment: The `NSEnumerator` approach is more efficient for 200,000 items when compared to the other two approaches but I doubt the OP is dealing with that many. And that link was a good read. +1

Answer (score 3):

If you're dead set on using fast enumeration here, you could set a flag that lets you skip each even iteration of the loop:

```
BOOL doThisOne = YES;
NSArray itemArray = [section itemArray];
for (id item in items) {
    if (doThisOne) {
        item1 = item;
        item2 = [itemArray objectAtIndex:1+[itemArray indexOfObject:item]];
    }
    doThisOne = !doThisOne;
}
```

*Note:* The code above throws a range exception if the number of items in the array is odd. Some of the other answers avoid this, but I think the best answer is simply not to use fast enumeration here.

It'd be so much simpler to use an enumerator, or just use a regular old for loop:

```
NSEnumerator *e = [[section items] objectEnumerator];
while (item = [e nextObject]) {
    item1 = item;
    item2 = [e nextObject];
}
```

or:

```
NSArray *itemArray = [section items];
for (int i = 0; (i + 1) < [items count]; i += 2) {
    item1 = [items objectAtIndex:i];
    item2 = [items objectAtIndex:i+1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(id item in array){
    if([array indexOfObject:item] % 2 != 0){
     item1 = item;
    }else{
     item2 = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach Chris...but I'm not sure -[indexOfObject:] runs in O(1). And even if it does, is it more costly than the "obvious" answer involving a for loop and local index variable? - "Anonymous" Critic

Comment: I wouldn't say that one is more "obvious" than the other, this is just how I solved the problem first in my mind. It's an even/odd problem so I think this is the easiest way to go about it. As far as performance is concerned, a local index variable could possibly (probably) be less costly but I stand by my modulus approach.

Comment: I don't think the question is about the modulus, it's about whether the -indexOfObject: method will require searching the array to find the index of the given object. That might be an O(1) operation, or it might be O(n). If the latter, the whole loop could become O(n^2) instead of O(n), obviously not desirable.

Comment: Oh, I know what you're saying. Obviously the further down the array has to compare objects to obtain the index, the longer it will take to run the loop. That's why I said it would probably be faster. If it's an array of ~50 objects, I would think the difference should be negligible. If you want the code to be scalable to a large array, you are certainly correct.

Comment: hypothetically, if each iteration of each loop takes 1 ms to execute, and if n == 50, then the O(n^2) solution would take 2.5 s to run, as opposed to the 50 ms the O(n) solution would take to run.

Answer (score 1):

```
int numItems = [section.items count];

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    item1 = [section.items objectAtIndex: i];
    item2 = ((i + 1) < count)) ? [section.items objectAtIndex: (i + 1)] : nil;
}
```