# Objective-C ugly code?

Tags: objective-c, performance, for-loop

I have some Objective-C code that does the job for me. But is it ugly (inefficient). Can it be performed better with for-each loops?

See this code please:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [careerIds count]; i++) {

    NSString *titleString = [[titles objectAtIndex:i] stringValue];
    if ([titleString isEqualToString:@""] || [titleString rangeOfString:@"Intresseanmälan"].location != NSNotFound) {
        // Don't add the id
    } else {
        [ids addObject:[[careerIds objectAtIndex:i] stringValue]];
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably not. It is a little bit ugly, but I think worrying about the efficiency in this case is probably misplaced.

Comment: If you're concerned about the speed, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482082/nsarray-loop-to-grab-objects/6482115#6482115) where @Deepak actually timed the various options and found that not using fast iteration is faster than using fast iteration if that means that you also have to `-indexOfObject`. Or at least it was in the case tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the code that you have is particularly ugly -- there's nothing at all wrong with using an indexed for loop as you've done. The only thing I might change would be to invert the sense of the `if` statement so that you avoid the empty `// Don't add the id` line. Here's one way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [careerIds count]; i++) {

    NSString *titleString = [[titles objectAtIndex:i] stringValue];

    if (([titleString length] > 0) && 
        ([titleString rangeOfString:@"Intresseanmälan"].location == NSNotFound))
    {
        [ids addObject:[[careerIds objectAtIndex:i] stringValue]];
    }

}
```

To get to the heart of your question, no, I don't believe it's possible to use the fast enumeration version of the `for` loop to iterate over the contents of two separate containers at the same time. You can use it with one, but as I pointed out in a comment, you then have to use `-indexOfObject:` to recover the index of the current object so that you can get the corresponding item from the other array using `-objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: You should be able to remove `([titleString length] > 0)` without a problem or probably just `titleString` to check if its not `nil` but I doubt even that would be necessary.

Comment: @Deepak `titleString` should never be `nil`, but it might legitimately be `@""`, in which case `rangeOfString` would return `NSNotFound` and the object addition would be performed, incorrectly.

Comment: @walkytalky aah! I see what you're saying. I didn't expect it to be `nil` but yeah, I was wrong about the `@""` part.

Comment: @Deepak, I could have said `![titleString isEqualToString:@""]`, but it's easy (to me) to miss that !, and I think using length > 0 better conveys "not empty". You're right that titleString should never be nil with the code above, but in a situation where the tested string might be nil, `[titleString length] > 0` does the expected thing (evaluates to NO).

Comment: In terms of making it less ugly (easier to read in future) you could add a well named `BOOL` like `BOOL isTitleValid = ([titleString length] > 0) && ([titleString rangeOfString:@"Intresseanmälan"].location == NSNotFound);` and then use the `isTitleValid` variable in the `if` statement. It just means you don't have to do a double take to figure out what you was originally checking.

Comment: @Paul.s, no argument there. A comment could also help. And you could always add a category to NSString with a `-isNotEmpty` method so that you never have to wonder again. ;-)

Comment: I like your solution @Paul.s! Thanks for everyone contributing with ideas!

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be performed better with for-each loops?

<s>Yes.</s>

```
for (id title in careerIds) {

    NSString *titleString = [title stringValue];
    if ([titleString isEqualToString:@""] || [titleString rangeOfString:@"Intresseanmälan"].location != NSNotFound) {
        // Don't add the id
    } else {
        [ids addObject:titleString];
    }
}
```

Or if you want to be really flash:

```
for (NSString* titleString in [careerIds valueForKey: @"stringValue"]) {

    if ([titleString isEqualToString:@""] || [titleString rangeOfString:@"Intresseanmälan"].location != NSNotFound) {
        // Don't add the id
    } else {
        [ids addObject:titleString];
    }
}
```

No. :-)

Comment: Check the question: the object being added is from a different source than the object being tested. So the answer is probably really "no".

Comment: Neither of these appears to do what the OP's code does. In the original code, `titleString` comes from the `titles` array, which doesn't appear anywhere in your code. If `careerIds` and `titles` are parallel arrays, then you must either join them into a single array first, or use `-indexOfObject:`, or use a traditional indexed for loop as in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming careerIds is a NSArray or NSMutableArray and that you're add NSString objects to it, you can do this:

```
for (NSString *titleString in careerIds) {

    if ([titleString isEqualToString:@""] || [titleString rangeOfString:@"Intresseanmälan"].location != NSNotFound) {
        // Don't add the id
    } else {
        [ids addObject: titleString];
    }
}
```

<strike>[ids addObject:[[careerIds objectAtIndex:i] stringValue]];</strike>

Comment: See my comment to @JeremyP's answer. This code does not replicate the original functionality.

Comment: Oh, and you're using `i` without declaring or defining it. Whoever upvoted this needs a stern talking to.

Comment: Whoops, guess I should have gone over it a bit more carefully. I was only looking at the for loop. I didn't do anything with the code inside it. Thanks for catching that. :)